# Is it possible to decouple re-rendering of some components when specific states change in react hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have created state called someState with useState and my page has 2 components (component A is function of someState, and component B of not.)

I wanted to only re-render component A when someState changes but does B as well.

```
const [someState, setSomeState] = useState(null);
const [message, setMessage] = useState(null);

const componentA = () => {
   console.log("component A");
   return (<div style={{position:someState}}>Hello World!</div>);
}

const ComponentB = (props) => {
   console.log('component B');
   return <div>Hope this is not re-rendered..</div>
}

return (
   <div>
     <div onClick={(e)=>{setSomeState(5);}>Update the position</div>     
     <div>{componentA()}
     </div>

     <ComponentB message={message}/>
   </div>
)
```

here when I clicked the button "update", I get two console log results (component A, component B)

Is there way to decouple the re-rendering of componentB?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Put the state that updates into a component which is a *sibling*, not a *parent*, of the one you want not to re-render - or, put that state into `ComponentA`:

```
const [message, setMessage] = useState(null);
return (
    <div>
        <ComponentA />
        <ComponentB message={message} />
    </div>
);
```

and

```
const componentA = () => {
    const [someState, setSomeState] = useState(null);
    return (
        <div>
            <div onClick={(e)=>{setSomeState(5);}>Update the position</div>     
            <div style={{position:someState}}>Hello World!</div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

If parent state changes, it and all its children will re-render. To prevent an element from re-rendering, make sure that neither it nor any of its ancestors change state.

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you don't want to move the state to the child components you can memoize the component(which you don't want to rerender).

```
const [someState, setSomeState] = useState(null);
const [message, setMessage] = useState(null);

const componentA = () => {
   console.log("component A");
   return (<div style={{position:someState}}>Hello World!</div>);
}

const ComponentB = (props) => {
   console.log('component B');
   return <div>Hope this is not re-rendered..</div>
}

const memoizedComponentB = react.useMemo(() => {
    return <ComponentB message={message}/>;
}, [message]) // only recompute this when message changes.

return (
   <div>
     <div onClick={(e)=>{setSomeState(5);}>Update the position</div>     
     <div>{componentA()}
     </div>
     {memoizedComponentB}
   </div>
)
```

You can also use [`React.memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo).

Answer (score 0):

`useMemo` is your friend here.

```
const [someState, setSomeState] = useState(null);
const [message, setMessage] = useState(null);

const componentA = React.useMemo(() => {
   console.log("component A");
   return (<div style={{position:someState}}>Hello World!</div>);
}, [someState])

const ComponentB = React.useMemo((props) => {
   console.log('component B');
   return <div>Hope this is not re-rendered..</div>
}, [])

return (
   <div>
     <div onClick={(e)=>{setSomeState(5);}>Update the position</div>     
     <div>{componentA()}
     </div>

     <ComponentB message={message}/>
   </div>
)
```